# How can I add a button with 100% width and position:fixed

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot of solutions here at stackoverflow but nothing is working.

```css
a.buttongc {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f5b220;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.gc-button-center {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 999999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="gc-button-center">
  <a href="#" class="buttongc startgc">test</a>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

I want to have a margin left and right but it is only working at the left side and the button goes over the scrollbar. any solution?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: box-sizing is not working.

Comment: what means 'not working' here?

Comment: If you just remove the width from the `a`, the box sizing will work correctly.

Comment: both width:100% are useless: https://jsfiddle.net/0r69a5zt/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing fancy needed. Just remove your `width: 100%` If display is `block`, and width is not supplied, the width will auto size to fit the parent.

```css
    a.buttongc{
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: #f5b220;
        color: #fff;
     font-size: 17px;
        height: 44px;
        line-height: 42px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
     margin:10px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        font-family: inherit;
        cursor: pointer;
     overflow:hidden;
       display: block;
        
    }
    
    .gc-button-center{
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      display:block;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 50px;
      z-index:999999999;
    
    }
```

```html
    <div class="gc-button-center">
    <a href="#" class="buttongc startgc">test</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: oh, this is really simple, very good. but is there a solution to include the scrollbar?

Comment: @desmeit Very difficult to say without having a view at how it looks like. Which scrollbar?

Answer (score 4):

Just change **width: calc(100% - 20px);** for subtract margin

```css
a.buttongc{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f5b220;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin:10px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-family: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;

}

.gc-button-center{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index:999999999;

}
```

```html
<div class="gc-button-center">
  <a href="#" class="buttongc startgc">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. This is working. Is there a possibility to include the scrollbar?

Comment: can you tell me in brief about including the scrollbar?

Comment: the margin is calculate 10px included the scrollbar. I want to set 10px without scrollbar.

Comment: @desmeit You can set margin based on width of scrollbar but if there is no scrollbar then it will not work as per requirement and for mobile and desktop width of scrollbar is different.